# I've combined two onedit scripts and only one is working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I combined the scripts to operate the two onedits. But only onedit1 works, and onedit2 doesn't work
I don't know which part I need to fix to make both of them work.
Should I add something to the onedit part? Or which part should I exclude?

```js
function onEdit(e){
  onedit1(e);
  onedit2(e)
}
function onedit1(e){
  var tabLists = "lists1";
  var tabValidation = "Questions_B";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
function onedit2(e){
  var tabLists = "lists2";
  var tabValidation = "Questions_R";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }

  }

    }

  }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `onedit2` inside `onedit1` but you never execute it. You only define it.

If you want to keep the two `onEdit` function apart then simply separate them so they can both be executed by the main `onEdit`:

```
function onEdit(e){
  onedit1(e);
  onedit2(e);
}

// onedit1
function onedit1(e){
  var tabLists = "lists1";
  var tabValidation = "Questions_B";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }
  }
}

// onedit2  
function onedit2(e){
  var tabLists = "lists2";
  var tabValidation = "Questions_R";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
    
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```